# How to make items start from left in each row? (product in ecommerce site)

Tags: php, html, css

```html
<?php 
 $active='Products';
include("includes/db.php");
include("functions/functions.php");
include("includes/header.php");
?>


<div id="content"><!-- #content Begin -->
       <div class="container"><!-- container Begin -->
           <div class="col-md-12"><!-- col-md-12 Begin -->
               
               <ul class="breadcrumb"><!-- breadcrumb Begin -->
                   <li>
                       <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                   </li>
                   <li>
                   <a href="shop.php">Products</a>
                   </li>
               </ul><!-- breadcrumb Finish -->
               
           </div><!-- col-md-12 Finish -->
           
           <div class="col-md-3"><!-- col-md-3 Begin -->
   
                <?php 
                    
                    include("includes/sidebar.php");
                    
                    ?>
               
           </div><!-- col-md-3 Finish -->
           
           <div class="col-md-9"><!-- col-md-9 Begin -->
           <?php  
                   if(!isset($_GET['cat']))
                   {
             
                     echo "

                      <div class='box'><!-- box Begin -->
                          <h1>All products</h1>
                          <p>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo deleniti accusamus, consequuntur illum quasi ut. Voluptate a, ipsam repellendus ut fugiat minima? Id facilis itaque autem, officiis veritatis perferendis, quaerat!
                          </p>
                      </div><!-- box Finish -->

                      ";
                       
                   }
            ?>
        
             <div class="row"><!-- row Begin -->
               
                   <?php 
                   
                     
                            
                         if(!isset($_GET['cat'])){
                            
                            $per_page=12; 
                             
                            if(isset($_GET['page'])){
                                
                                $page = $_GET['page'];
                                
                            }else{
                                
                                $page=1;
                                
                            }
                            
                            $start_from = ($page-1) * $per_page;
                             
                            $get_products = "select * from products order by 1 DESC LIMIT $start_from,$per_page";
                             
                            $run_products = mysqli_query($con,$get_products);
                             
                            while($row_products = mysqli_fetch_array($run_products))
                            {
                                
                                $pro_id = $row_products['product_id'];
        
                                $pro_title = $row_products['product_title'];

                                $pro_price = $row_products['product_price'];

                                $pro_img = $row_products['product_img'];
                                
                                echo "
                                
                                    <div class='col-4'  >
                                        <div class='product'>
                                         <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>
                                             <img  src='images/coins/$pro_img'>
                                         </a>
                                         <div class='text'>
                                         <h4 
                                         style=' color: #555; 
                                         padding-top: 10px; 
                                          
                                         text-overflow: ellipsis;
                                         white-space: nowrap;
                                         overflow: hidden;'>
                                             <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='text-decoration:none'> $pro_title </a>
                                         </h4>
                                         <p class='price'>$$pro_price</p> 
                                         <p class='buttons'>
                                         <a class='btn btn-primary' href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'> 
                                            <i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i> Add To Cart
                                         </a> </p>

                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                ";
                             }
                        ?>
               
               </div><!-- row Finish -->
               
               <center>
                   <ul class="pagination"><!-- pagination Begin -->
                     <?php
                             
                    $query = "select * from products";
                             
                    $result = mysqli_query($con,$query);
                             
                    $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);
                             
                    $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);
                             
                        echo "
                        
                            <li>
                            
                                <a href='shop.php?page=1'> ".'First Page'." </a>
                            
                            </li>
                        
                        ";
                             
                        for($i=1; $i<=$total_pages; $i++){
                            
                              echo "
                        
                            <li>
                            
                                <a href='shop.php?page=".$i."'> ".$i." </a>
                            
                            </li>
                        
                        ";  
                            
                        };
                             
                        echo "
                        
                            <li>
                            
                                <a href='shop.php?page=$total_pages'> ".'Last Page'." </a>
                            
                            </li>
                        
                        ";
                             
                            }
                            
                        
                     
                     ?> 
                       
                   </ul><!-- pagination Finish -->
               </center>
                
                <?php 
               
   
               
               getpcatpro()
               
               ?>  
               
           </div><!-- col-md-9 Finish -->
           
       </div><!-- container Finish -->
   </div><!-- #content Finish -->
   




    <?php

    include("includes/footer.php");

    ?>


    <script src="js/jquery-331.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-337.min.js"></script>








</body>

</html>
```

[This is the image of my ecommerce website, which loads the products randomly if less than 4 per row.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnlNa.png)

My issue is, as you can see the image in the last row is randomly placed.
If the images are less than 4 per row like here, it is placed anywhere.
How to make it start from to left every time, no matter how many items.
Sorry ignore the mess, I am an absolute beginner and did this following multiple tutorials.

```css
.col-4 {
  flex-basis: 25%;
  padding: 10px;
  min-width: 200px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='col-4'>
  <div class='product'>
    <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>
      <img src='images/coins/$pro_img'>
    </a>
    <div class='text'>
      <h4 style=' color: #555; 
                                         padding-top: 10px; 
                                          
                                         text-overflow: ellipsis;
                                         white-space: nowrap;
                                         overflow: hidden;'>
        <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='text-decoration:none'> $pro_title </a>
      </h4>
      <p class='price'>$$pro_price</p>
      <p class='buttons'>
        <a class='btn btn-primary' href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>
          <i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i> Add To Cart
        </a>
      </p>
```

Comment: These codes are not enough to understand. Where is col-4 in?

Comment: Hi, sorry I a new to stackoverflow as well, I just updated my question, THank you

Answer (score 0):

Your mark-up is slightly off. I believe you're using bootstrap 3 so in that case you need to add rows to contain your columns like so:

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
        <div class="col-md-4">.col-md-4</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

In your case starting from your container, wrap all the child column divs in a row as you did for the nested one in the col-m-9 div.

```
<?php
$active = 'Products';
include("includes/db.php");
include("functions/functions.php");
include("includes/header.php");
?>


<div id="content"><!-- #content Begin -->
    <div class="container"><!-- container Begin -->
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12"><!-- col-md-12 Begin -->

                <ul class="breadcrumb"><!-- breadcrumb Begin -->
                    <li>
                        <a href="index.php">Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="shop.php">Products</a>
                    </li>
                </ul><!-- breadcrumb Finish -->

            </div><!-- col-md-12 Finish -->        
            <div class="col-md-3"><!-- col-md-3 Begin -->

                <?php

                include("includes/sidebar.php");

                ?>

            </div><!-- col-md-3 Finish -->
            <div class="col-md-9"><!-- col-md-9 Begin -->
                <?php
                if (!isset($_GET['cat'])) {

                    echo "

                      <div class='box'><!-- box Begin -->
                          <h1>All products</h1>
                          <p>
                              Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Explicabo deleniti accusamus, consequuntur illum quasi ut. Voluptate a, ipsam repellendus ut fugiat minima? Id facilis itaque autem, officiis veritatis perferendis, quaerat!
                          </p>
                      </div><!-- box Finish -->

                      ";

                }
                ?>

                <div class="row"><!-- row Begin -->

                    <?php


                    if (!isset($_GET['cat'])){

                    $per_page = 12;

                    if (isset($_GET['page'])) {

                        $page = $_GET['page'];

                    } else {

                        $page = 1;

                    }

                    $start_from = ($page - 1) * $per_page;

                    $get_products = "select * from products order by 1 DESC LIMIT $start_from,$per_page";

                    $run_products = mysqli_query($con, $get_products);

                    while ($row_products = mysqli_fetch_array($run_products)) {

                        $pro_id = $row_products['product_id'];

                        $pro_title = $row_products['product_title'];

                        $pro_price = $row_products['product_price'];

                        $pro_img = $row_products['product_img'];

                        echo "
                                
                                    <div class='col-4'  >
                                        <div class='product'>
                                         <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'>
                                             <img  src='images/coins/$pro_img'>
                                         </a>
                                         <div class='text'>
                                         <h4 
                                         style=' color: #555; 
                                         padding-top: 10px; 
                                          
                                         text-overflow: ellipsis;
                                         white-space: nowrap;
                                         overflow: hidden;'>
                                             <a href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id' style='text-decoration:none'> $pro_title </a>
                                         </h4>
                                         <p class='price'>$$pro_price</p> 
                                         <p class='buttons'>
                                         <a class='btn btn-primary' href='details.php?pro_id=$pro_id'> 
                                            <i class='fa fa-shopping-cart'></i> Add To Cart
                                         </a> </p>

                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                ";
                    }
                    ?>

                </div><!-- row Finish -->

                <center>
                    <ul class="pagination"><!-- pagination Begin -->
                        <?php

                        $query = "select * from products";

                        $result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

                        $total_records = mysqli_num_rows($result);

                        $total_pages = ceil($total_records / $per_page);

                        echo "
                        
                            <li>
                            
                                <a href='shop.php?page=1'> " . 'First Page' . " </a>
                            
                            </li>
                        
                        ";

                        for ($i = 1; $i <= $total_pages; $i++) {

                            echo "
                        
                            <li>
                            
                                <a href='shop.php?page=" . $i . "'> " . $i . " </a>
                            
                            </li>
                        
                        ";

                        };

                        echo "
                        
                            <li>
                            
                                <a href='shop.php?page=$total_pages'> " . 'Last Page' . " </a>
                            
                            </li>
                        
                        ";

                        }


                        ?>

                    </ul><!-- pagination Finish -->
                </center>

                <?php


                getpcatpro()

                ?>

            </div><!-- col-md-9 Finish -->
        </div>
    </div><!-- container Finish -->
</div><!-- #content Finish -->


<?php

include("includes/footer.php");

?>


<script src="js/jquery-331.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-337.min.js"></script>


</body>

</html>
```

Lastly `<center>` is no longer valid mark-up